# SVG : Remove gap between two rects

Tags: python, css, svg

I use `svgwrite` Python package to generate a diagram in SVG. My objective is to add black or white squares depending upon the array of 0s and 1s. Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import svgwrite

CSS_STYLES = """
    .background { fill: white; }
    .blacksquare { fill: black; }
    .whitesquare { fill: white; }
"""

def draw_board(dwg, data, block_sz):
    def group(classname):
        return dwg.add(dwg.g(class_=classname))
    
    # setup element groups
    white_squares = group("whitesquare")
    black_squares = group("blacksquare")
    
    board_height = data.shape[0]
    board_width = data.shape[1]
    
    # draw squares
    for x in range(board_width):
        for y in range(board_height):
            xc = x * block_sz
            yc = y * block_sz 
            square = dwg.rect(insert=(xc, yc), size=(block_sz, block_sz))
            (white_squares if data[y][x] == 1 else black_squares).add(square)

def main():
    data = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]) # data represents an array of 0 and 1s. 0 means black square and 1 means white square

    block_sz = 10 # units per square
    num_y_blocks = data.shape[0]
    num_x_blocks = data.shape[1]
    BOARD_WIDTH = "{}cm".format(num_x_blocks * block_sz) # size of the PCB board
    BOARD_HEIGHT = "{}cm".format(num_y_blocks * block_sz) # size of the PCB board
    BOARD_SIZE = (BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT)

    dwg = svgwrite.Drawing("output.svg", size=BOARD_SIZE)
    dwg.viewbox(0, 0, num_x_blocks * block_sz, num_y_blocks * block_sz)
    dwg.defs.add(dwg.style(CSS_STYLES))
    
    # set background
    dwg.add(dwg.rect(size=('100%','100%'), class_='background'))
    draw_board(dwg, data, block_sz)
    dwg.save()

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

For the input array `[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]`, I get the following `ouput.svg`:

[image: SVG diagram]

The SVG for the above diagram is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="20cm" version="1.1" viewBox="0,0,50,20" width="50cm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[
    .background { fill: white; }
    .blacksquare { fill: black; }
    .whitesquare { fill: white; }
]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="background" height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0"/>
  <g class="whitesquare">
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="0" y="10"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="10" y="0"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="20" y="0"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="20" y="10"/>
  </g>
  <g class="blacksquare">
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="0" y="0"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="10" y="10"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="30" y="0"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="30" y="10"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="40" y="0"/>
    <rect height="10" width="10" x="40" y="10"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### The problem: The white lines (the gap) between the rects.

I need to remove the white lines between the rects.
[image]

I have tried adding the stroke attribute and tried to play around with the margin (following some answers in the SO) but didn't get the expected result.

I'm open to any solutions. I just want to convert the array of 1s and 0s to squares with a specified size in SVG format.

Please help.

### Solution:

Based on @RobertLongson, adding `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` to the CSS styling removes the gap. Below is the corrected CSS:

```
CSS_STYLES = """
    .background { fill: white; }
    .blacksquare { fill: black; shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
    .whitesquare { fill: white; shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
"""
```

Expected SVG:

[image: Corrected SVG]

Comment: turn off antialiasing via shape-rendering: crispEdges;

Comment: @RobertLongson It worked!! Thank you.